# Masking in R - Confusing behavior from a new package

Tags: r, oop, namespaces

When I attached the package `ffbase` for the first time it alerted me that the functions `%in%` and `table` were being masked from the base package. I use both functions quite a lot, so I immediately investigated what this means and I am not really sure I understand what's going on here.

As far as I can tell, for `table` this means that a new method was added:

```
methods(table)
[1] table.default* table.ff
```

And for `%in%`, it's truly been overwritten so the default is the `ff` version, with `base` playing backup:

```
getAnywhere(`%in%`)
2 differing objects matching '%in%' were found in the following places
package::ffbase
package:base
namespace:base
namespace:ffbase
```

I have two questions now. The first is - if a new method is added an S3 generic, then why would you need to warn about masking? In my mind, `table` isn't truly masked because doesn't R just figure out what data type I have and dispatch the correct method?

And secondly, if you have actually overwritten a function then why does it still work if I do base functionality without specifying the right namespace?

```
x <- c(1, 23)
23 %in% x
[1] TRUE
```

I would have assumed I would have needed to use `base::%in%` to get this right?

I suppose this second question really boils down to - I trust R when it comes to the generic method dispatch, because the point of a having a class is to provide some way to signal what method you're supposed to use. But if you have this system where package functions (not associated with a class) just get loaded in order of package load, then I don't understand how R knows when the first one it encounters isn't going to work?

Comment: Package maintainers should and usually do take care when masking `base` functions. You can always look at the code - `ffbase::'%in%'` is defined [here on line 101](https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/blob/master/pkg/R/ffmatch.R), and see that it checks if the item being matched is an `ff_vector` or `ffdf` object, and if not it uses the normal `base::'%in%'` definition. Your assumption about `table` being an S3 generic is incorrect - you can look at `base::table` and see that it does not use S3 dispatch. Rather, `ffbase` makes iit a S3 generic, and setting the default method to `base::table`.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks for the informative comment @Gregor. I assume that the general lesson to be learned here is that if a package creator/maintainer is masking base, and if you're interested in how, you should read the source. Because otherwise - I was looking for a pattern in how things are designed, and in this case `ffbase` is just an interesting example that may not be representative of how others do things? As a bonus, my question linked to a bunch of others about writing robust code in R that I wasn't seeing before when I was researching.